# Distance between court & crowd in Basketball

Tags: basketball

I was recently watching a NBA match and what I want to know is that why is the crowd (including cameramen) so close to the end of the court? Why don't they keep an higher distant gap? I've often seen players bumping into the crowd. So why do they still maintain such a small gap?

Answer (score 1):

Because fans *want* to be that close to the action, and are prepared to pay seriously big amounts of money for those seats. As with any other sport, the NBA is in the business of entertainment, so you give the punters what they'll pay for.

Comment: But that restricts the players to play freely

Comment: If a basketball player needs the space significantly beyond the end of the court, they're not playing effectively, which for a franchise like that is much more important.